# jasperreports TextField wrapping among pages in doc format

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-word

I've got fairly long TextField that must be wrapped beetween pages.

But it gets cutted by page border.

[image: hiding]

[image: not hiding]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

the only thing that saved me, is top and bottom padding.